# Consume REST API with Android

Tags: android, rest, android-asynctask

I have created a rest API using Spring boot it works perfectly i can add and retrieve data with `JSON` format:

```
[{
    "idProduct": 1,
    "description": null,
    "prix": 0.0
}, {
    "idProduct": 2,
    "description": "firstProduct",
    "prix": 52413.0
}, {
    "idProduct": 3,
    "description": "PRD3",
    "prix": 41413.0
}]
```

I am trying to consume it with an Android client, but when I execute it, it runs without exception, though doesn't display anything.

the android Activity :

```
package com.hassen.client_test;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnChercher;
    private TextView tvJson;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnChercher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnchercher);
        tvJson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvJson);
        btnChercher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   new JsonTask().execute("http://192.168.1.20:8080/products");
                   //   http://hmkcode.appspot.com/rest/controller/get.json
               }


           }
        );
    }


    public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection=null;
            BufferedReader reader=null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line="";

                while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                String finalJson = buffer.toString();

                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("parentObject");
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);

                String description = finalObject.getString("description");

               // String titre = finalObject.getString("title");

                return description;





            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(connection!=null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }

                if(reader!=null){
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            tvJson.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code for the JsonTask class

Comment: i dont write a JsonTask class , what is it and how can i write it???

Comment: "it doesn't display anything" Well, you don't print anything at any point in your code. What exactly do you want to display ?

Comment: Why did you include all that Spring code in the question? Also, you might want to look into using Volley or Retrofit instead of using AsyncTask. That will allow you to not re-write the extra `HttpURLConnection` code

Comment: i have to use my local api , i dont know how to use Volley or Retrofit with local api if it is possible please show me how

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(json string);

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){

    JSONObject c = arr.getJSONObject(i);        
    String product= c.getString("idProduct");
    String description= c.getString("description");
    String prix= c.getString("prix");
}
```

Now you can return which field you want.